# How to encase a command with redirection for executing with sudo

Tags: linux, bash

Sorry if the title is misleading, I can't think how to write it.

Inside a script I'm trying to pass a command that has a redirection, to a function for executing it with sudo. The function has proven to work with normal commands, but as this command has a redirection, it seems to try execute the redirection outside the function and throws an error due to permissions.
I've tried to encase the whole command in `$( )` but this creates a new env, that is not what I want (also failing).
This is an example for what I'm trying to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

execute_command() {
  local input=$@
  sudo bash -c "$input"
}

execute_command echo "Content of file: $content" > /etc/myfile
execute_command $(echo "Content of file: $content" > /etc/myfile) # Also fails
```

Comment: You can't store a redirection operation in a variable and make it work (without any possible hacks)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a single string:

```
execute_command 'echo "..." > /etc/myfile'
```

I would recommend against trying to define such a general-purpose function; the redirection occurs before `execute_command` (and thus `sudo`) runs. Rather, just use `sudo` directly to execute the command that needs to open the file.

```
echo "..." | sudo tee /etc/myfile > /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem that I didn't reflect in my question is that the file contents is based in a variable that must be interpreted. I think you guessed that. I'll modify the post to reflect it.

Comment: In fact, I temporary used a solution composed by creating the file first and then moving it. But that ends in mor work (file creator<>root). I hoped it could exist a direct solution. And avoid running sudo several times.